# jquery autocomplete with results in div

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, autocomplete

This is the first time I have tried to use jQuery Auto Complete and I have it working however I work like to edit it slightly but finding it a bit hard.

What I am trying to do is use the auto complete to search through the product database using a product code that is typed into a input field. Then have a div that will show the matching Product name as the result. At the moment I have the standard auto complete where is shows the results below the input box, which is not what I want.

Then the tricky part is to leave the product code that was typed in the input box and just show the product name in the results div. I can then use this to complete my add to cart form.

Below is the code that I have so far:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 
$(function() {
    $( "#username" ).autocomplete({
        source: "source.asp",
        minLength: 5
});
});
</script>


<input type="text" id="username">
```

The source.asp file generates the data link as below:

```
[{"id":"product ID","value":"Product Name"}]
```

This then is read by the jQuery auto complete function.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

To create a wrapper div

```
$( "#username" ).data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderMenu=function(){
    // Create your div here
}
```

To render individual items inside that div

```
$( "#username" ).data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem=function(){
    // render your items here, skip it if it creates undesired result
}
```